# How to add new option to select if radiobutton is changed using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to add new "items" to a given `<select>` using jQuery.
If one of the both possibiities (Countries) is checked, the "select-Box" below should change the list `<options>`.

This is my code:

```js
$("input:radio[name=radio-1]").change(function() {
  //alert ($(this).val());
  if ($(this).val() == "aut") {
    for (i = 18; i < 21; i++) {
      $('#selectCosts').append($('<option>', {
        value: i,
        text: "Option " + i
      }));
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="country">
  <h2>Land</h2>
  <form name="selectPowerCost">
    <fieldset>
      <div id="selectCountry" class="col col-md-12">
        <!-- Österreich -->
        <div class="radio pull-left" style="margin-top: -5px; min-width:150px;">
          <label for="radio-1">Österreich<span class="country-aut">&nbsp;</span></label>
          <input class="left-20" type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-1" value="aut">
        </div>
        <!-- Deutschland -->
        <div class="radio pull-left left-10" style="min-width:150px;">
          <label for="radio-2">Deutschland<span class="country-ger">&nbsp;</span></label>
          <input class="left-20" type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-2" value="ger">
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</div>
<div id="stromkostenProKW">
  <h2>Stromkosten pro KWh</h2>
  <div class="pull-left" style="margin-top: -5px">
    <form>
      <select id="selectCosts" name="selectCosts" class="selectpicker" title="Wählen Sie Ihre Stromkosten pro KWh">
         
        </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code won`t run. Why?

Comment: Have you try regular html append like this? `$('#selectCosts').append('<option value="'+i+'">Option '+i+'</option>');`

Comment: Have you try regular html append like this? `$('#selectCosts').append('<option value="'+i+'">Option '+i+'</option>');`

Comment: @ThomasWeber Did I help you?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes you helped me. As I a a Beginner I have to change the code to have a good standard. So I have to implement the Method addEventListener() and the Event  DOMContenLoaded and some more Changes.... thank you very much for your suport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is change option for combobox depending on the selected radio button. What you need to do is to clear the combobox options first before adding new options.

```js
$("input:radio[name=radio-1]").change(function() {
    //alert ($(this).val());
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#selectCosts').find('option').remove().end();
    if (val == "aut") {
        for (i = 18; i < 21; i++) {
            $('#selectCosts').append($('<option>', {
                value: i,
                text: "Option " + i
            }));
        }
    } else if(val == "ger") {
        for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            $('#selectCosts').append($('<option>', {
                value: i,
                text: "Option " + i
            }));
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <div id="country">
        <h2>Land</h2>
        <form id="selectPowerCost" name="selectPowerCost">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="col col-md-12" id="selectCountry">
                    <!-- Österreich -->
                    <div class="radio pull-left" style="margin-top: -5px; min-width:150px;">
                        <label for="radio-1">Österreich<span class="country-aut">&nbsp;</span></label> <input class="left-20" id="radio-1" name="radio-1" type="radio" value="aut">
                    </div><!-- Deutschland -->
                    <div class="radio pull-left left-10" style="min-width:150px;">
                        <label for="radio-2">Deutschland<span class="country-ger">&nbsp;</span></label> <input class="left-20" id="radio-2" name="radio-1" type="radio" value="ger">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="stromkostenProKW">
        <h2>Stromkosten pro KWh</h2>
        <div class="pull-left" style="margin-top: -5px">
            <form>
                <select class="selectpicker" id="selectCosts" name="selectCosts" title="Wählen Sie Ihre Stromkosten pro KWh">
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your support. It helped me really. I will keep your suggestion in mind. Please consider my text in the previous comment (as answer to Miles07)

Comment: It`s me once more again. I copied your "solution" in to my HTML/JS Environment. It won`t run. See at: [link]http:://presentation.wei-ag.net/sites/rechner2.html[/link]. Why? Maybe you have a little bit of time and may help me one again... Thank you very much.

Comment: I think the problem is in your css.. I can see that #selectCosts dimensions are (0.5px by 34px)

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer. I solved the problem. The included "bootstrap-select.min.js" made some occured some problems.

Answer (score 0):

You only check if the country Austria is checked and not if Germany is checked. 
Also i would add `$("#selectCosts").empty();` before the loop to empty the items inside the list.

**EDIT**

You could also replace this part:

`$('#selectCosts').append($('<option>', {
  value: i,
  text: "Option " + i
}));`

With this suggestion made by @Taufik Nur Rahmanda:

```
$('#selectCosts').append('<option value="'+i+'">Option '+i+'</option>');
```

---

```js
$("input:radio[name=radio-1]").change(function() {
  //alert ($(this).val());
  if ($(this).val() == "aut" || $(this).val() == "ger") {
    $("#selectCosts").empty();
    for (i = 18; i < 21; i++) {
      $('#selectCosts').append($('<option>', {
        value: i,
        text: "Option " + i
      }));
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="country">
  <h2>Land</h2>
  <form name="selectPowerCost">
    <fieldset>
      <div id="selectCountry" class="col col-md-12">
        <!-- Österreich -->
        <div class="radio pull-left" style="margin-top: -5px; min-width:150px;">
          <label for="radio-1">Österreich<span class="country-aut">&nbsp;</span></label>
          <input class="left-20" type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-1" value="aut">
        </div>
        <!-- Deutschland -->
        <div class="radio pull-left left-10" style="min-width:150px;">
          <label for="radio-2">Deutschland<span class="country-ger">&nbsp;</span></label>
          <input class="left-20" type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-2" value="ger">
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</div>
<div id="stromkostenProKW">
  <h2>Stromkosten pro KWh</h2>
  <div class="pull-left" style="margin-top: -5px">
    <form>
      <select id="selectCosts" name="selectCosts" class="selectpicker" title="Wählen Sie Ihre Stromkosten pro KWh">
         
        </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys/Girls/Developer!

Thx a lot for your support.

I solved my Problem. All suggestions are working fine.

I had included a "bootstrap-select.min.js" which made some conflicts and result in problems. As I excluded this .js-File everything works fine.

Thank you very much!

Here is the code I am using (only JS):

```
function init() {
$("input:radio[name=radio-1]").change(function() {
var val = $(this).val();
$('#selectCosts').find('option').remove().end();
if (val == "aut") {
    for (i = 16; i < 22; i++) {
        $('#selectCosts').append($('<option>', {
            value: i,
            text: "Kosten pro KWh: " + i + " ct"
        }));
    }
} else if(val == "ger") {
    for (var i = 26; i < 33; i++) {
        $('#selectCosts').append($('<option>', {
            value: i,
            text: "Kosten pro KWh: " + i + " ct"
        }));
    }
}
```

});

}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);